# SoundTouchNet DLL processor architecture mismatch

Tags: c#, winforms, soundtouch

I have a windows forms application which uses SoundTouchNet dll. I am facing this warning during build time:

Warning 1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "SoundTouchNet", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

I know this means that SoundTouch dll is for running on 32 bit machines as the warning says. I want to know if this can create problems when running on 64 bit machines and if yes, what is my solution?
I cannot find 64 bit version of the dll

Answer (score 0):

Your windows forms application is (probably) compiled as "AnyCPU". This means it will run on 32-bit Windows as 32-bit application and on 64-bit Windows as 64-bit application.
If you compile your application for the "x86" architecture, to match the architecture of the third-party assembly, you'll still be able to execute it on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows OSes, the difference will be your application will remain as 32-bit application also under 64-bit Windows.

**Update:**
Changing the architecture of your application to "x86" should not lead to any problems when running on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Will this affect the performance in anyway?
Or cause failure during application running?

Comment: When I changed it to x86 it gave errors stating SoundTouchNet assembly not found

Comment: @bboyetricks, so VS fails to compile your application or your application failed to start, stating it cannot find the 3-rd party assembly?

Comment: @bboyetricks, please ensure that 3-rd party assembly gets referenced (Node References of your project in the Solution Explorer) and the reference is valid.